# Logarithm Equations: Solving for variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is similar to the last question I asked, but I am just unsure about how to work this problem. The equation is $2\ln(x) + 3 = 0$ Please show the steps.

Comment: First solve for $\ln(x)$. Then use the fact that $e^{\ln(x)} = x$.

Comment: So i would subtract 3 and divide by 2 on both sides. Then what after that?

Comment: You want to eliminate the $\ln$ to solve for $x$. Applying $e^\Box$ on both sides does this, since this is the inverse of $\ln$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2ln(x)+3=0$

$2ln(x)=-3$

Divide both sides by $2$

$ln(x)=-3/2$

We use that $e^y=x$

Let $y=-3/2$

$x=e^{-3/2}$

$x=.2231$

Comment: @IlaIsabelle No problem! Hope I helped! I saw most of your questions and thought I would help you out!

Comment: Yes you helped a lot!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, solve for $\ln(x)$.
$$2\ln(x)+3=0$$
$$2\ln(x)=-3$$
$$\ln(x)=-\frac32$$
Remember that if $\log_a(b)=y$, then $a^y=b$.
$$\ln(x)=\log_e(x)=-\frac32$$
In this case, $a=e$, $b=x$, and $-\dfrac32=y$.
$$x=e^{-3/2}$$
This can be rewritten as:
$$x=\exp\left(-\frac32\right)$$
That is your solution. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you! You helped tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

$$2\ln x=-3\\
\implies \ln x=\dfrac{-3}{2}\\
\implies x=\exp\left(\dfrac{-3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you again! I am so glad you keep answering all of my questions!

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Sure!